# error: request for member 'size' in 'data', which is of non-class type 'int [5]'

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int data[] = {3,6,7,8,9};
    for(int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++){
            data[i] = i * i;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<data.size(); i++){
            cout << data[i] <<endl;
    }
}
```

Hello, I am practicing with my C++ program in terms of array operations. But I got the error message that I cannot figure it out why:

> error: request for member 'size' in 'data', which is of non-class type 'int [5]'

So anyone can help to clarify this? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you could use a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Perhaps instead of a regular array you're looking for https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: Perhaps you were thinking of `std::size(data)` - but I'd still recommend using a `std::array` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a plain old array, which does not have any functions.

You should instead switch to `std::array` or `std::vector`, where you'll be able to use the member function `size()`:

```
std::array<int, 5> data = { 3, 6, 7, 8, 9};
std::vector<int> data = { 3, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

You will need to `#include <array>` or `#include <vector>` respectively.

Thanks to [@Galik from the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51737883/error-request-for-member-size-in-data-which-is-of-non-class-type-int-5/51737937#comment90436465_51737937), if you're using C++17 or newer, you can also use the [`std::size`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) which works on arrays, as well as std containers like `vector` and `array`:

```
int data[] = {3,6,7,8,9};
for(int i = 0; i < std::size(data); i++)
```

Alternatively, you can just use a for ranged loop on your current array when you don't need the index, like when you print it:

```
int data[] = {3,6,7,8,9};
for (auto i : data)
    std::cout << i << " ";
```

which prints `3 6 7 8 9`

Comment: Thanks very much, this solves my problem! I might need to change other references in the future.